# Karnaugh map simplification

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I'm working through an example that looks like a fairly simple Karnaugh map and simplification, but I feel stupid that I can't seem to understand the correct answer.

**This is the map:**
[image: K-Map]

**My groupings:**
[image: K-Map grouping]

This is the equation:
[image: Eq]

But I don't know how it simplifies to the correct answer here:
[image: Eq]

I understand why the NOT A goes outside of the bracket, but I don't see how the C OR NOT C just becomes a C inside the bracket?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Create a full table for both formulae. *Are* they equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Check for solution. Grouping should be done using 2 quads

Comment: Note that you can use Markdown and LaTeX here to typeset mathematics, rather than using an image. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction to Latex.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you are trying to group, you must use the biggest possible group. A group's size has to be a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8...).

In this case you need to make 2 groups:

cells 4, 5, 12, 13: $A'D$

cells 8, 9, 12, 13: $A'C$

Represented as SOP: $A'D+A'C$

Using the  Distributive Law:

$A'D+A'C=A'(C+D)$

---

About the way that you tried:

You grouped:

cells 4, 5: $A'C'D$

cells 8, 9, 12, 13: $A'C$

Assuming that you didn't notice the bigger grouping option, the expression that you have can still be simplified using Boolean Laws:

$A'C'D+A'C=A'(C'D+C)$ **Distributive Law**

According  to one of the laws: $A+A'B=A+B$

So: $A'(C'D+C)=A'(C+D)$